# How do I install a NuGet package into the second project in a solution?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, nuget

I'm currently working on a solution that initially contained one project (`My.First.Project.Name`). I've installed Castle Windsor by executing:

```
Install-Package Castle.Windsor
```

I've just added another project (`My.Second.Project.Name`) to the solution and want to install Castle Windsor into this project also, but when I run `Install-Package Castle.Windsor` again, I get the error:

> 'Castle.Core 2.5.2' already installed
>   'Castle.Windsor 2.5.2' already installed
>   My.First.Project.Name already has a reference to 'Castle.Core 2.5.2'
>   My.First.Project.Name already has a reference to 'Castle.Windsor 2.5.2'

So my question is: *How do I persuade the NuGet Package Manager to install the package into the second project*?

Answer (score 327, accepted):

There's 3 approaches :).
In NuGet 1.1 (The latest release) we've improved powershell pipelining so you can do this:

```
Get-Project -All | Install-Package SomePackage
```

That will install "SomePackage" into all of your projects. You can use wildcards to narrow down which projects:

```
Get-Project Mvc* | Install-Package SomePackage
```

That will use wildcard semantics (in this case, find all projects that start with mvc).

```
Get-Project SomeProject | Install-Package SomePackage
```

That will install SomePackage into SomeProject and nothing else.

Comment: and 3th approache is simply calling `Install-Package SomePackage` to install it on current project.

Comment: But what is "current" project?

Comment: The selected one in the dropdown

Comment: @jalal That doesn't work, just tried it in VS2015.  The package always installed to the first project, not the current one.

Comment: @Eternal21 You can select current project from project drop-down in Package Manager Console window.

Comment: Pressing the tab key after Get-Project will give a drop-down of projects to choose from and can save a few keystrokes.

Answer (score 143):

There's two approaches.

As you already learned, the Package Manager Console has a drop down that lists the projects in your solution.

The other approach is to use the -Project flag. Nice thing about that is it gives you Intellisense with the project names! For example:

```
Install-Package SomePackage -Project MvcApplication2
```

Answer (score 84):

The answer is, embarassingly, blindlingly simple.

The "Package Manager Console" has a drop-down titled "Default Project" in its toolbar, changing the project there to `My.Second.Project.Name` then allows `Install-Package Castle.Windsor` to install the package into the second project.

Comment: you adverb usage is unbelievably, unquestionably, delightful

Answer (score 17):

In Visual Studio 2015 (as of Nuget v3.1.2) the syntax is now:

```
Install-Package ThePackage -ProjectName YourProjectName
```

Note: -Project**Name** vs -Project

Answer (score 9):

In Visual Studio, you can go to `Tools -> NuGet Package Manager -> Manage NuGet Packages for the entire Solution`. From there, select the Nuget Package you want to share between projects and click `Manage`. This will allow you to add a specific installed NuGet Package to whichever other projects you want.

Comment: I never knew about this window. Super powerful, nice!

Comment: I have spend one hour looking around this functionnality ! Thank you very much for this one !

Comment: I do not see a "Manage" button.  Where is it supposed to be?

Answer (score 7):

If you just need to copy packages from existing project to the new one, just copy and/or modify packages.config file to the new project and run `Update-Package -reinstall -Project YourProjectName`

Answer (score 0):

There is also the option to force a reinstall. With certain problems, this helped me.

```
Update-Package Microsoft.Owin -Reinstall
```